# CrafterCMS: application.properties location

Tags: crafter-cms

Hi I am still new to Crafter and needs to connect to an external database in my project. I need the `local.properties` or `application.properties` file, just like in the Spring framework, but I can't seem to find it. Where is it located in Crafter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's located under `bin/apache-tomcat/shared/classes/crafter/engine/extension/server-config.properties`